# sql query doesn't work when i use (if,BEGIN,END)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a table with many columns. i trying to build a php file that will send data to that table. but before it sends it needs to check if the user already exist by checking user email. i don't know how to fix the query.

this is my code

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "users");

mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_client = utf8");
mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_connection = utf8");
mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_results = utf8");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$qry = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE userEmail = $_post['userEmail'] ) BEGIN
INSERT INTO `users`( `userPassword`, `userFirstName`, `userLastName`, `userSex`, `userEmail`,
`userArea`, `userDate`, `userPicture`, `userPhoneNumber`, `userSkypeName`,`userDetails`, `userCategories`)
VALUES ( '" . $_POST["userPassword"] . "' , '". $_POST["userFirstName"] ."' , '". $_POST["userLastName"] ."',
" . $_POST["userSex"] . ", " . $_POST["userEmail"] . "  '" . $_POST["userArea"] . "' ,
 '". $_POST["userDate"] ."' , '". $_POST["userPicture"] ."',
 " . $_POST["userPhoneNumber"] . ", " . $_POST["userSkypeName"] . " , '" . $_POST["userDetails"] . "',
  '". $_POST["userCategories"] ."' )"
  END
  ;



mysqli_query($connection,$qry);

mysqli_close($connection);
echo $qry;



?>
```

this is the query i tried in phpmyadmin

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE userEmail = "abc@gmail.com" ) BEGIN 
INSERT INTO `users`( `userPassword`, `userFirstName`, `userLastName`, `userSex`, `userEmail`,
`userArea`, `userDate`, `userPicture`, `userPhoneNumber`, `userSkypeName`,`userDetails`, `userCategories`)
VALUES ( "password" , "fName", "Lname",
"Male", "abc@gmail.com " ,"abcx" , "28-12-2016","pic address",
 "09368157474", "skypeEmail" , "some details","abdjdgjsbsjsbsksb" );
  END  ;
```

this are the errors:

[image]

Comment: There is no select if begin Syntax in mysql what are you trying todo

Comment: sorry without the select in the beginning @Jens

Comment: I'm trying to add a user with all his details but before, to do a check if the user already exsit by the email. if there is already the same email in database he will not add the user @Jens

Comment: @Jens MySQL does have an if() function. The problem is that the OP tries to build a compound sql statement block (begin ... end) outside of a strored proc / function, which is not allowed in MySQL.

Comment: @Shadow what should I do?

Comment: @Shadow That is what i mean. I never sayed that there is no if funtion in mysql.

Comment: @jens what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to create a [unique index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) on the email column. If a user were to register with an existing email address, then the unique index would prevent the insertion. By querying the returned error it is easy to see that a unique index constraint was violated, therefore you tell the user that the email address had been used before.

Comment: how should I change my query?

Comment: Use your favourite MySQL management program (phpmyadmin, sqlyog, etc), that's the easiest way. Otherwise, you have to manually add a unique index using an `alter table` statement.

Comment: I'm working with phpmyadmin. but why Is my query isn't good?how can I fix it?

Comment: Which part of the answer is not clear? Create a unique index on email field and then just simply try to insert a record with an existing email address. MySQL will not let you do that.